# Fourier Transform of operator

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

> Let $A = (a_{jk})$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix. Let $u \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and define $L_Au \in C(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by: $$L_Au = -\sum_{j,k=1}^n a_{jk}\partial^2_{x_jx_j}u$$ Assume $u(\infty) = 0$ and $\partial_{x_j}u(\infty) = 0,  (j=1,\cdots,n).$ Prove that: $$\hat{L_Au}(\xi) = 4\pi^2\sum_{j,k=1}^n a_{jk}\xi_j\xi_k\hat{u}(\xi)$$

I tried starting with definitions:

$$\hat{L_Au}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} L_Au(x)e^{-2\pi i \xi \cdot x} dx= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} -\sum_{j,k=1}^n a_{jk}\partial^2_{x_jx_j}u(x)e^{-2\pi i \xi \cdot x} dx$$

This doesn't seem to be leading anywhere, so I would assume there's a better way to solve this problem without using the definition of the Fourier transform directly. Since I have $2\pi$ in the exponent but a $4\pi^2$ in the solution, that may suggest using Parseval's Identity or something related. Any help with how to proceed would really be appreciated!

Comment: Are you familiar with how fourier transforms act on derivatives? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Differentiation

Comment: @AlexR. Well that certainly looks like a better way to go. I assume there's a way to modify it from the one-dimensional case to the multi-dimensional case

Comment: Yes, the modification is trivial since the multivariate fourier transform is multiplicitive in $e^{-2\pi \xi_ix_i}dx_i$.

Comment: Integration by parts is a good way to start, that's why you have the data for the function and it's derivative at infinity